# createObjectURL unsupported in Opera

Tags: browser, blob, opera

Checking this adress: http://caniuse.com/#feat=bloburls you can see this is the only desktop browser with no support for this feature. 
How can I find a workaround for this without to much change in my code?

```
var jpeg = NewBlob(imgData.array.buffer, "image/jpeg");
 var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(jpeg);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your use case is to show a thumbnail of a picture the user selects, you can create a data  uri for file she uploads. Tested under Opera 12.13 to work even with a couple meg image:

```
<script>
function handleFiles(files) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(evt) {
        document.getElementById("img1").src = evt.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
}
</script>

<img id="img1">
<form>
    <input type="file" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)">
</form>
```